# Не вызывается callback потока в C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Имеется приложение на C# ASP.NET MVC. В нем присутствуют потоки. Упрощенный пример кода приведен ниже:

```
//...
public void f() {
   debugLog("1");
   Thread a = new Thread(b);
   debugLog("2");
   a.Start();
   debugLog("3");
}
public void b() { 
   debugLog("thread started");
   //...
}
public void debugLog(string message) { 
   File.AppendAllText(@"C:\debug.log", message);
}
```

При тестировании на рабочем ноутбуке все работает. Но если развернуть приложение на IIS и запустить на сервере, то callback потока перестает вызываться. То есть в логах только "1 2 3" без "thread started".

В чем заключается проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: А почему оно должно рабоать? Вы поток запкстили, окончания потока не ждете, да ещё и пишете текст в один и тот же файл параллельно - я бы сказал, тут непонятно, что должно отработать в итоге.

Comment: tym32167, да хоть в разные файлы писать, без разницы. На локальном ПК работает же.

Comment: Если в конце функции f() вызвать `a.Join();` то по прежнему не будет отрабатывать?

Comment: tym32167, не помогло.

Comment: ставили breakpoint? смотрели, в отладке вызывается? Что выводит? Если после `a.Join();` поставить `debugLog("10");` отработает?

Comment: tym32167, breakpoint не поставить, ибо это уже деплой проекта, запущенный на IIS.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70562/discussion-between-essle-and-tym32167).

Comment: Хм, тогда надо все залогировать, все вызовы, до вызовов, после вызовов

Comment: в чат не могу - фаерволл не пустит

Comment: Есть возможность связаться в другом месте? Для более быстрого общения.

Comment: Не, нет. Я отвечаю только когда у меня есть время. Да и ничего более, что я тут уже предложил, на ум не приходит.

Comment: tym32167, хорошо, и на этом спасибо)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вопрос решил. Проблема была в настройках пула IIS.

Диспетчер служб IIS → Пулы приложений → Выбираем нужный пул → Дополнительные параметры → Меняем значение строки "Удостоверение" на **LocalSystem**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]